# redux-form: Dynamically defining handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

Since I am pretty new to the React ecosystem my description and way of doing things may be way off but I hope you can follow my issue.

I have a parent Component that gets a form injected from the router and maps state and the action creators to the properties.

Container.js

```
import * as actionCreators from "../actionCreators";

export default class ComponentA extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ComponentA">
        {this.props.children} //<--Form
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    listItems: state.get("listItems")
  };
}

export const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(ComponentA);
```

The component that gets render with `{this.props.children}` is the following form.

Form.js

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };   

  render() {
    const { fields: {title, description}, handleSubmit} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="create-project-form">
        <h1>Create Project</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" className="form-control"/>
          <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
          <textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10" className="form-control"></textarea>
          <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handleSubmit}>Create</button>

        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connectReduxForm({
  form: "from",
  fields: ["title", "description"]
})(Form);
```

Router

```
const routes = <Route component={App}>
  <Route path="/" component={Container}/>
  <Route path="/a" component={Container}>
    <Route path="/a/create" component={Form}/>
  </Route>
</Route>;

render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>{routes}</Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("content"));
```

The Problem is `handleSubmit` is not undefined, but it is non of my actions. I actually don't expect that it is magically set to the correct actionCreator but how do I pass in the function? I tried the action name instead of `handleSubmit` but then the function is undefined. Every example I saw passes the handleSubmit function manually into the Form component, but I can't do that because the Form is set by the Router.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to pass your field info to your `<input>`.

`<input
  type="text"
  {...title}  // <-------- that (it contains the "name" prop)
  className="form-control"/>`

2. You can pass any anonymous function to `handleSubmit`:

`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => {
  // do your submit stuff here and return a Promise if you want the
  // this.props.submitting flag to be set for the duration of the promise
})}>`

Does that help? [See also](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/209#issuecomment-153061970).

Comment: thanks. As I understand it I should inject a function that gets executed on submission. I can implement the function directly inside the form component like in your example (2),  but I can't seem to pass a function into the props. Something like `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(create)}>`. I think this is a general redux problem and not specific to redux-form but maybe you see what's wrong. Can I pass something to {this.props.children}? I actually thought react-redux's connect takes care of that, but that's not the case.

Comment: @KenavR A bit late but to pass the function being called you pass it as 'onSubmit' and then just bind to {handleSubmit} in the form and onSubmit will automatically get called